# Blank White screen blinks when navigating between screens in windows phone phonegap app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am facing a problem in the phonegap app, in the phonegap application, when we are navigating from one screen to another screen, a blank white screen blinks.

1)How can I avoid that blank white screen coming?

2)It is happening in windows phone phonegap app, anything specially I need to do to avoid it?

Please let me know

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your main css

```
      html, body { direction:ltr; background:url('../img/background.png') no-repeat left top;}
```

Or add background:yourcolor